# angular project eslint settings issue

Tags: angular, eslint

I am wondering why if i put the `/* eslint-disable ... */` inside the file eslint works fine and the rules are ignored, but if I move the same rules on the .eslintrc.json inside the rules array as the documentation said, it doesn't work

below an example[image]

Do you have any idea why the global disabled rules don't work ?
Am i missing something?

ADD the missing file  .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "error"
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
      ],

      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules/"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/promise/no-floating-promises": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
  }
}
```

DEBUG MODE

[image]

Thank you

Comment: we'd need to see the whole `eslintrc.json` to understand what it does !

Comment: Might want to run `eslint --debug [options] [file or directory]` to see what happens behind the scene. You can find more here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#options

Comment: thank you i update the missing information